# MATLAB: Missing Frameworks on mex-compile – Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: matlab, compilation, core-audio, mex, portaudio

I have been trying to get my head around some errors I get when compiling a MATLAB function written in C (on Mac OS X). The function [msound](http://www.hoertechnik-audiologie.de/web/file/Forschung/Software.php#msound) is provided precompiled for Windows and Linux by my university and is the basis for some further functions concerning audio recording and playback. Since I'm a Mac-User I thought it would be pretty neat to have it compiled into a Mac-version, too.

From the sourcecode and its compiler-function for Linux I tried to reverse-engineer a Mac-Version of the compiler-instructions, but I keep getting errors resulting in a failed compilation. Here is what I put together as compiler-function so far:

```
function compile_msound_unix

disp('Building msound ...')

szOptions = '';
szDefines = '';
szPaths   = '';
szFiles   = '';
szLibs    = '';

szOptions = sprintf( '%s %s', szOptions, '-output msound'       );
szOptions = sprintf( '%s %s', szOptions, '-largeArrayDims'      );

% Add main file.
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'msound.c' );

% Add basic PortAudio include paths and files.
szPaths = addPath( szPaths, 'portaudio/include'                         );
szPaths = addPath( szPaths, 'portaudio/src/common'                      );
szPaths = addPath( szPaths, 'portaudio/src/os/unix'                     );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/common/pa_allocation.c'      );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/common/pa_converters.c'      );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/common/pa_cpuload.c'         );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/common/pa_debugprint.c'      );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/common/pa_dither.c'          );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/common/pa_front.c'           );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/common/pa_process.c'         );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/common/pa_ringbuffer.c'      );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/common/pa_skeleton.c'        );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/common/pa_stream.c'          );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/common/pa_trace.c'           );
% Host
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/os/unix/pa_unix_hostapis.c'  );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/os/unix/pa_unix_util.c'      );

% Add PortAudio path for: Apple Core Audio API
disp('    Using ''Apple Core Audio API'' ...')

% Defines
szDefines = addDefine( szDefines, 'PA_USE_COREAUDIO' );
szDefines = addDefine( szDefines, '__MACOSX_CORE__');
% PortAudio
szPaths = addPath( szPaths, 'portaudio/src/hostapi/coreaudio' );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core_blocking.c' );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core_utilities.c' );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c' );
% Libs
% szLibs  = addLib ( szLibs , '/full/path/to/library?' );

% Build msound MEX-file using default compiler.
eval( [ 'mex', szOptions, szDefines, szPaths, szFiles, szLibs ] );

function szCmd = addFile  ( szCmd, szFile )
    szCmd = sprintf( '%s "%s"'  , szCmd, szFile );
function szCmd = addPath  ( szCmd, szPath )
    szCmd = sprintf( '%s "-I%s"', szCmd, szPath );
function szCmd = addDefine( szCmd, szName )
    szCmd = sprintf( '%s "-D%s"', szCmd, szName );
function szCmd = addLib   ( szCmd, szLib  )
    szCmd = sprintf( '%s "-l%s"', szCmd, szLib  );
function szCmd = addLibPath( szCmd, szPath )
    szCmd = sprintf( '%s "-L%s"', szCmd, szPath )
```

I already eliminated a few other errors, but right now I'm stuck with the following MATLAB console output:

```
Building msound ...
    Using 'Apple Core Audio API' ...
msound.c: In function 'msoundDeviceInfo':
msound.c:3042: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
msound.c:3044: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
msound.c:3046: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
msound.c:3048: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
portaudio/src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c: In function 'AudioIOProc':
portaudio/src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:1911: warning: 'AudioConverterFillBuffer' is deprecated (declared at /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Headers/AudioConverter.h:641)
portaudio/src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:2080: warning: 'AudioConverterFillBuffer' is deprecated (declared at /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Headers/AudioConverter.h:641)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_mxCreateScalarDouble", referenced from:
      _msoundDeviceInfo in msound.o
  "_AudioDeviceSetProperty", referenced from:
      _setBestFramesPerBuffer in pa_mac_core_utilities.o
      _AudioDeviceSetPropertyNowAndWaitForChange in pa_mac_core_utilities.o
     (maybe you meant: _AudioDeviceSetPropertyNowAndWaitForChange)
  "_AudioDeviceGetProperty", referenced from:
      _setBestFramesPerBuffer in pa_mac_core_utilities.o
      _AudioDeviceSetPropertyNowAndWaitForChange in pa_mac_core_utilities.o
      _setBestSampleRateForDevice in pa_mac_core_utilities.o
      _GetChannelInfo in pa_mac_core.o
      _PaMacCore_Initialize in pa_mac_core.o
      _OpenStream in pa_mac_core.o
      _PaMacCore_GetChannelName in pa_mac_core.o
      ...
  "_AudioDeviceGetPropertyInfo", referenced from:
      _setBestFramesPerBuffer in pa_mac_core_utilities.o
      _setBestSampleRateForDevice in pa_mac_core_utilities.o
      _GetChannelInfo in pa_mac_core.o
      _PaMacCore_Initialize in pa_mac_core.o
      _PaMacCore_GetChannelName in pa_mac_core.o
  "_AudioDeviceAddPropertyListener", referenced from:
      _AudioDeviceSetPropertyNowAndWaitForChange in pa_mac_core_utilities.o
      _OpenAndSetupOneAudioUnit in pa_mac_core.o
  "_AudioDeviceRemovePropertyListener", referenced from:
      _AudioDeviceSetPropertyNowAndWaitForChange in pa_mac_core_utilities.o
      _CloseStream in pa_mac_core.o
  "_AudioHardwareGetPropertyInfo", referenced from:
      _PaMacCore_Initialize in pa_mac_core.o
  "_AudioHardwareGetProperty", referenced from:
      _PaMacCore_Initialize in pa_mac_core.o
  "_AudioUnitUninitialize", referenced from:
      _CloseStream in pa_mac_core.o
  "_CloseComponent", referenced from:
      _CloseStream in pa_mac_core.o
      _OpenAndSetupOneAudioUnit in pa_mac_core.o
  "_AudioConverterDispose", referenced from:
      _CloseStream in pa_mac_core.o
  "_AudioConverterReset", referenced from:
      _StartStream in pa_mac_core.o
  "_AudioOutputUnitStart", referenced from:
      _StartStream in pa_mac_core.o
  "_AudioOutputUnitStop", referenced from:
      _StopStream in pa_mac_core.o
      _AudioIOProc in pa_mac_core.o
  "_AudioUnitGetProperty", referenced from:
      _StopStream in pa_mac_core.o
      _startStopCallback in pa_mac_core.o
      _OpenAndSetupOneAudioUnit in pa_mac_core.o
  "_AudioUnitReset", referenced from:
      _StopStream in pa_mac_core.o
  "_AudioDeviceGetCurrentTime", referenced from:
      _GetStreamTime in pa_mac_core.o
      _AudioIOProc in pa_mac_core.o
  "_FindNextComponent", referenced from:
      _OpenAndSetupOneAudioUnit in pa_mac_core.o
  "_OpenAComponent", referenced from:
      _OpenAndSetupOneAudioUnit in pa_mac_core.o
  "_AudioUnitSetProperty", referenced from:
      _OpenAndSetupOneAudioUnit in pa_mac_core.o
  "_AudioUnitAddPropertyListener", referenced from:
      _OpenAndSetupOneAudioUnit in pa_mac_core.o
  "_AudioConverterNew", referenced from:
      _OpenAndSetupOneAudioUnit in pa_mac_core.o
  "_AudioConverterSetProperty", referenced from:
      _OpenAndSetupOneAudioUnit in pa_mac_core.o
  "_AudioUnitInitialize", referenced from:
      _OpenAndSetupOneAudioUnit in pa_mac_core.o
  "_AudioUnitRender", referenced from:
      _AudioIOProc in pa_mac_core.o
  "_AudioConverterFillBuffer", referenced from:
      _AudioIOProc in pa_mac_core.o
  "_CFStringCreateWithFormat", referenced from:
      _PaMacCore_GetChannelName in pa_mac_core.o
  "_CFStringGetLength", referenced from:
      _PaMacCore_GetChannelName in pa_mac_core.o
  "_CFStringGetCString", referenced from:
      _PaMacCore_GetChannelName in pa_mac_core.o
  "_CFRelease", referenced from:
      _PaMacCore_GetChannelName in pa_mac_core.o
  "___CFConstantStringClassReference", referenced from:
      CFString in pa_mac_core.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

    mex: link of ' "msound.mexmaci64"' failed.

??? Error using ==> mex at 208
Unable to complete successfully.

Error in ==> compile_msound_unix at 51
eval( [ 'mex', szOptions, szDefines, szPaths, szFiles, szLibs ] );
```

The major problem seems to be the **`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64`**. I did some research on that, I now know that some frameworks might be missing. But I'm very new to this kind of programming (and compiling on the Mac) and I could use some help.

The function I try to compile is based on the [PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com) Audio-I/O which supports CoreAudio on the Mac. As you see in my compiler-function, I already included the files of PortAudio which are necessary, but I'm still missing the corresponding Libraries/Frameworks. I already tried to provide them with lines like:

```
szLibs  = addLib ( szLibs , '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework' );
```

but without any success. I really hope you guys have ideas how to make this run. I am using **Mac OS X 10.7.3 Lion, and I have Xcode installed and gcc-4.2 is running. MATLAB Version is 2011a (v7.12)**

Thanks in advance, Jan.

Comment: So I continued to work on the issues and fixed the warnings at line 3042, 3044, 3046 and 3048: They were created by `mxCreateScalarDouble` being replaced by `mxCreateDoubleScalar` function in MATLAB 6.5 and is already removed in my version. So that is gone, along with the first of the missing symbols, which was cause by aforementioned replacement of `mxCreateDoubleScalar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heureka! I finally found it out myself: Since I simply took a lot of the code from the Linux mex-compiling-function of *msound*, the problem was how the neccesary frameworks were linked in. As it turns out that the `" ... "` (double quotes) at the paths and files were wrong for it to work, and only the frameworks actually need them because they get passed along to *gcc*. I removed them from the `addFile`, `addPath` and so on and finally all files got recognized and the frameworks linked, so that all the missing symbols went away. My epiphany was mostly initiated by [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924701/how-to-link-during-matlabs-mex-compilation) and specifically its correct answer.

In case of interest, here is the fully working compiler-function:

```
    function compile_msound_mac

bOldMexApi = false;

disp('Building msound ...')

szOptions = '';
szDefines = '';
szPaths   = '';
szFiles   = '';
szFrameworks    = 'LDFLAGS="\$LDFLAGS';

szOptions = sprintf( '%s %s', szOptions, '-output msound'       );

% Use the old MATLAB C API on newer MATLAB versions.
if( ~verLessThan('matlab','7.3') )
    if( bOldMexApi )
        % Use backward compatible old MATLAB C API
        szOptions = sprintf( '%s %s', szOptions, '-compatibleArrayDims' );
    else
        szOptions = sprintf( '%s %s', szOptions, '-largeArrayDims'      );
    end
end

% Add main file.
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'msound.c' );

% Add basic PortAudio include paths and files.
szPaths = addPath( szPaths, 'portaudio/include'                         );
szPaths = addPath( szPaths, 'portaudio/src/common'                      );
szPaths = addPath( szPaths, 'portaudio/src/os/unix'                     );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/common/pa_allocation.c'      );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/common/pa_converters.c'      );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/common/pa_cpuload.c'         );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/common/pa_debugprint.c'      );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/common/pa_dither.c'          );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/common/pa_front.c'           );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/common/pa_process.c'         );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/common/pa_ringbuffer.c'      );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/common/pa_skeleton.c'        );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/common/pa_stream.c'          );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/common/pa_trace.c'           );
% Host
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/os/unix/pa_unix_hostapis.c'  );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/os/unix/pa_unix_util.c'      );

% Add PortAudio path for: Apple Core Audio API
disp('    Using ''Apple Core Audio API'' ...')
% Defines
szDefines = addDefine( szDefines, 'PA_USE_COREAUDIO' );
szDefines = addDefine( szDefines, '__MACOSX_CORE__');
% PortAudio
szPaths = addPath( szPaths, 'portaudio/src/hostapi/coreaudio'                        );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core_blocking.c' );
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core_utilities.c');
szFiles = addFile( szFiles, 'portaudio/src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c '         );
% Frameworks
szFrameworks = addFramework ( szFrameworks , 'CoreAudio'     );
szFrameworks = addFramework ( szFrameworks , 'AudioToolbox'  );
szFrameworks = addFramework ( szFrameworks , 'AudioUnit'     );
szFrameworks = addFramework ( szFrameworks , 'CoreServices'  );
% 
% 
% % Closing Tag for Frameworks
szFrameworks = sprintf('%s"', szFrameworks);

% Build msound MEX-file using default compiler.
eval( [ 'mex', szOptions, szDefines, szPaths, szFiles , szFrameworks ] )

disp('Done.')

function szCmd = addFile  ( szCmd, szFile )
    szCmd = sprintf( '%s %s'  , szCmd, szFile );
function szCmd = addPath  ( szCmd, szPath )
    szCmd = sprintf( '%s -I%s', szCmd, szPath );
function szCmd = addDefine( szCmd, szName )
    szCmd = sprintf( '%s -D%s', szCmd, szName );
function szCmd = addFramework( szCmd, szFramework)
    szCmd = sprintf( '%s -framework %s', szCmd, szFramework);
```